# How to implement Login Page in Secured Angular + Spring Boot based Web App

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a web application based on Angular as front end and Spring boot as back-end and I want to secure it. I want to make it like,
when a user enters URL it should open login page.
I don't want to use jsp on the server side. I want to know how to implement a login page on the front end and apply security.

Comment: you can try spring auth 2 or BasicAuthentication and use Angular js Routing

Answer (score 1):

you can:

- put your login page at the top of your angular Route. The other routes are [lazy-loaded](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) and safe with a [guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad) and redirect to your login if user is not connected.
- If the user is not connected and the REST calls to your server send 'unauthorized' (401),
  then you can intercept every http call with an [interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) and redirect to your login page.

Comment: Thanks For the Help.